# Data Step View and Data Step: Needs to be run "separately" at first to make the script working

Tags: sas, dataview, datastep

This question arises from two others I had regarding sending a batch job and also wraping that respective script in a macro for further loops (see here:

- [Run SAS batch jobs via SH files: SAS script contains export to csv - where is / how to get the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080582/run-sas-batch-jobs-via-sh-files-sas-script-contains-export-to-csv-where-is/49089286#49089286)
- [SAS data step view and data wrap in a macro for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079828/sas-data-step-view-and-data-wrap-in-a-macro-for-loop/49089265#49089265)

My code works as follows:

```
[1] I define some macro variables
[2] I create a data step view
[3] My data step uses the previous data step view to make some calculation
[4] Export the results
```

The first time: when I run [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080582/run-sas-batch-jobs-via-sh-files-sas-script-contains-export-to-csv-where-is/49089286#49089286)+[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079828/sas-data-step-view-and-data-wrap-in-a-macro-for-loop/49089265#49089265), and then run [3]+[4]. The code works. I need to do this once and then I can run [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080582/run-sas-batch-jobs-via-sh-files-sas-script-contains-export-to-csv-where-is/49089286#49089286)+[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079828/sas-data-step-view-and-data-wrap-in-a-macro-for-loop/49089265#49089265)+[3]+[4] (the entire script) altogether. However, if I don't do this "split" run my code gives me the following error message:

```
116        data xtemp2;
117             set _v_&tables;
117             set _v_&tables;
                 ___
                 180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

118             by symbol date time;
                 __
                 180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

119             format itime rtime time12.;
.
.
.
```

and so on, every line afterwards shows the same error. Please note that there are two times line 117, however my code has it only once.

I tried to put a sleep function in between the data steps, but the problem is the same.

Comment: You can sometimes get hard to explain errors she the macro variables are quoted in atypical ways. Try wrapping the macro variable resolution as  %unquote(&tables). Use options mprint when troubleshooting. If 'tables' is a list of tables then the set statement is improper with respect for the generated statement.

Comment: Dear Richard, thank you very much. I have not set quotation marks around the variable, i.e. %let tables = cq_1998.

Comment: Does your code actually have two set statements, one right after the other?  Or is the log just showing the same line twice.  The normal reason that a SET statement is not valid is because the DATA statement did not run. You probably have a missing semi-colon higher up in the program.  Add an extra 'run;` statement before the data step to help you debug.

Comment: It's not *really* possible to tell what's happening.  You'd have to include more about your code (i.e., all of it).

Comment: Dear all, Richard has found the solution. I added extra "run;" statements before each of the data steps and now the code (run as a whole), the code wrapped in a macro as well as the batch job works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As @Joe points out, there wasn't enough information here.  However, judging by your answer to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49080582/run-sas-batch-jobs-via-sh-files-sas-script-contains-export-to-csv-where-is), the issue seems to be here:

```
73          '9:30:00't and '16:00:00't) and     mode = 12 and            EX =
73       ! 'N';           run;   *Screen data to find the trade before a set
73       ! time interval   data xtemp2;       set _v_&tables;       by symbol
                                           ___
                                           180
 73       ! date time;       format itime rtime time12.;       if
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

Your 'Screen data to find...' comment is not terminated with a semicolon, and so the `data xtemp;` statement becomes the end of the comment.  Hence there is no `data` statement preceding the `set` statement.

Did you run this comment when you ran it 'step by step'?

Comment: Thanks Allan, the solution is as suggested by Richard: Adding extra "run;" before each data step and all of the sudden it works!